# Gitpython check repo cloned

Tags: python, django, gitpython

I am working with Django Rest Framework, build some functionality interacts with git repository.
I am using gitpython.
Now, I used clone_from to clone remote repository.

```
repo = Repo.clone_from("REMOTE_REPOSITORY", "LOCAL_PATH")
```

But sometimes it fails with some network connection problems.
How can I know repo is cloned correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your command in a try, except block

`try:
    repo = Repo.clone_from("REMOTE_REPOSITORY", "LOCAL_PATH")
except git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError:
    ....`

Catching a sample exception above.
A full list of exceptions is available at http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.exc

Comment: Thanks - I will try with this.